# django pagination and RawQuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-pagination

is there a way to paginate a rawqueryset using django's inbuilt pagination?
when i cast it to a list , it throws an error in my face ...TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found. Is there  a way around this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I managed to achieve it using the following:

```
paginator = Paginator(files, 12)
paginator._count = len(list(files))
```

The code in django.core.paginator.py:

- checks for whether _count is set
- if not then tries to run .count() which doesn't exist
- if not then tries plain len

len on a raw_queryset doesn't work but converting the actual paginator object to a list works find for me in Django 1.3

Comment: Obviously len(list(files)) is very memory inefficient for large raw query sets. Given you know the query that was run you could run another query with COUNT(*) instead and assign that to the paginator._count as long as the number of results isn't going to change between each query.
Alternatively different DBMS have ways you could embed the total number of rows in every row of the query if the query results are constantly changing.

Comment: Unfortunately, [RawQuerySet.__getitem__()](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/query.py?rev=17381#L1517) calls list(self) anyway - so it's going to be totally loaded into memory as soon as you call `paginator.get_page()`. To avoid that, I think you'd have to subclass RawQuerySet, and make sure your raw SQL has LIMIT/OFFSET - and even then, you're going to lose the result cache of a normal queryset, so accessing qs[0] twice will hit the DB twice.

Comment: Yes it will hit twice. I just discovered it for myself too. So its best you write VERY efficient sql for that raw queryset and instead of  passing raw queryset to len(list()) and to paginator you first evaluate the queryset by looping over it. Like l = [item for item in queryset] and then pass that l to both paginator and len(l). This gives you only one database call.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the attribute count manually for your RawQuerySet object:

```
items = Item.objects.raw("select * from appitem_item")

def items_count():
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select count(*) from appitem_item")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    return row[0]

items.count = items_count
```

for @Rockallite

```
>>> class A():
...    def b(self):
...        print 'from b'
... 
>>> 
>>> (A()).b()
from b
>>> def c():
...    print 'from c'
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.b = c
>>> a.b()
from c
```

Comment: django.core.paginator.Paginator looks for `count()` method. So setting the `count` property doesn't work.

Comment: Why, did you test it? Of course, it's a hack but I used it. I mean that in python you can replace one method by another.

Comment: Rockallite, I added the code in order to illustrate how this hack works

Answer (score -1):

```
qs.filter(**pfilter).distinct().extra(select={'test': 'COALESCE(`psearch_program`.`eu_price`, 999999999)'}).extra(order_by=['test'])
```

Comment: -1: explain what is being done, with what is compatibility to, etc.