# How to get count on raw SQL Query in Django & then start applying Pagination

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have Shop model class. I am passing a QueryString to raw Django ORM to get all non duplicate records + 1 record from duplicates.

Below is the query:

```
   qs = Shop.objects.raw(select a.* from customers a INNER JOIN (SELECT city ,MIN(id) as id FROM customers GROUP BY city) AS b ON a.city = b.city AND a.id = b.id)
```

Here I get a Raw Query Set.I want to know the count of queried result.
How I can proceed?

For Pagination:

```
page_object = Pagination(qs, 2)
page_count = page_object.num_pages
```

After executing above line i am getting an error as:

```
TypeError: object of type 'RawQuerySet' has no len()
```

Can someone have any idea?How can i apply pagination to my raw queryset.

Whatever things i am trying is because i am using MySQL as DB.

```
"pagination = Paginator(qs, records_per_page) 
totalPageCount = pagination._count = len(list(qs))"
```

I got the error on 2nd line as **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BY created' at line 1**

One thing i just want to make sure is it possible to count the records from a raw QuerySet If so then how?

Comment: Not entirely sure but I think you either need to make another raw query to get the count or you could not use a raw query with some overhead but overcome this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django pagination and RawQuerySet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152984/django-pagination-and-rawqueryset)

Comment: After applying same concept
 **"pagination = Paginator(qs, records_per_page)
  totalPageCount = pagination._count  = len(list(qs))"** I got the error on 2nd line as  `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BY created' at line 1`

Comment: Then update the question. State clearly that you tried the solution that was pointed as a duplicate question and got this new error.

Comment: How can i count the records based on raw query set?

Comment: Question Updated..Please see