# How to use raw SQL in Django Admin's get_queryset?

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlite

I am trying to use `Model.objects.raw()` in Django Admin but end up with a generic database error: "Something's wrong with your database installation. Make sure the appropriate database tables have been created, and make sure the database is readable by the appropriate user."

**admin.py**

```
class ChapterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields':['title','shorthand','description',]})
    ]
    list_display = ('shorthand','title')

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super(ChapterAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        sql = "SELECT * FROM myapp_chapter"
        queryset = Chapter.objects.raw(sql)
        return queryset
```

**models.py**

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=800, blank=True, null=True)
    shorthand = models.SlugField(max_length=3, unique=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.shorthand
```

Everything functions if `queryset` is set to `Chapter.objects.all()` instead of `Chapter.objects.raw(sql)`, so I initially assumed that my raw SQL was incorrect. I also read that errors can occur if `Models.objects.raw()` fails to return rows. However, running `SELECT * FROM myapp_chapter` in `dbshell` returns everything normally. **How do I get a queryset using raw SQL in Django Admin?**

For context on why I am choosing to use raw SQL, the `shorthand` contains a mixture of numeric and alphanumeric values that I need sorted naturally:

```
1
10
11
4
5
7A
7B
```

I get the results I want in dbshell using `SELECT * FROM myapp_chapter ORDER BY shorthand*1, shorthand`:

```
1
4
5
7A
7B
10
11
```

However, I couldn't find a way to achieve this result without using raw SQL. **Is there a better way to achieve this without using raw SQL?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django create admin list from raw query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37015928/django-create-admin-list-from-raw-query)

Answer (score 0):

Getting the SQL from a query is not all that hard: [Getting the SQL from a Django QuerySet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748295/getting-the-sql-from-a-django-queryset)
It's only rarely the right solution though, besides debugging I wouldn't recommend it.

The better solution would be to either use `extra()` through the Django ORM or by creating an extra column (which will be loads faster since the latter can  use an index): [Django QuerySet ordering by expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926931/django-queryset-ordering-by-expression)